# Load Image and video from url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, request, loadimage

I'm having troubles when I have to Load image from url. I get this url on a response from a POST to server.

So I have the POST funtion below:

```
public void getDataStruct() 
{

    string url = " myurl";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("id", "2");
    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}


IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    // check for errors
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Data[] jsonData = JsonHelper.FromJson<Data>(www.text);


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.Length; i++) 
        {
            switch(jsonData[i].tipo)
            {
            //Image
            case 0:

                GameObject plno = GameObject.Find ("Plane").gameObject;
                LoadImageFromUrl planeScript = (LoadImageFromUrl)plno.GetComponent (typeof(LoadImageFromUrl));
                planeScript.url = jsonData[i].url;

                break;

                //video
            case 1:
                GameObject video = GameObject.Find ("Video1").gameObject;
                VideoPlaybackBehaviour videocript = (VideoPlaybackBehaviour)video.GetComponent(typeof(VideoPlaybackBehaviour));
                videocript.youtubeVideoIdOrUrl=jsonData[i].url;
                break;


            case 2:
                break;
            }
        }

    } 
    else {
        MobileNativeMessage msg = new MobileNativeMessage("Error", "Error");
    }  
}
```

I don't know why but when I do this the image/video don't show..its because that render code is inside the request function? I tested without having to POST and I just hardcoded the urls and works.

the LoadFunction:

```
public class LoadImageFromUrl : MonoBehaviour {

    public string url;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start () {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GameObject plno = GameObject.Find ("Plane").gameObject;
            LoadImageFromUrl planeScript = (LoadImageFromUrl)plno.GetComponent (typeof(LoadImageFromUrl));
            planeScript.url = jsonData[i].url;
```

You assign the url, now you must call download coroutine from LoadImageFromUrl  component. Change your class to something like this:

```
public class LoadImageFromUrl : MonoBehaviour {

public string url;

public void Download()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadRoutine());
}

// Use this for initialization
IEnumerator DownloadRoutine () {
    Texture2D tex;
    tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
}
}
```

And add

```
planeScript.Download()
```

after

```
planeScript.url = jsonData[i].url;
```

Same with video

Comment: Thanks for the post I tried and it works but you have to Download () before not after. Please I will mark as a correct answer but you have to change it ;)

Comment: @FranciscoCastro you mean download and then assign url?

Comment: no assign and then Download you said add Download and after assign

Comment: @FranciscoCastro Thant's what I ment :) call Downlad after assign meaning assign before download, there was no 'and after', just after.

Comment: sorry misunderstood :)